# how do I make path names compatible with different OSs?

Tags: java, path, relative-path

I used to know it, but I know there is a way in java to make sure the path works in all OSs (Windows uses a different "/" system than Unix based systems).  What do I have to do to create a file path name that works with all systems?

EDIT: I wasn't sure if this is what I meant, but I think the file path will end up being relative.

Also, what's the difference between File.separator and File.pathSeparator ?

Comment: Are you referring to the slashes only? What about the drive letter in Windows vs / in Linux/Unix

Comment: @Danish, maybe the OP is only working with relative paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use `File.separator` or `File.separatorChar`for this purpose.
Check the `File` class javadoc for more info on this.

edit:
Difference between `separator` and `pathSeparator`. The first separates the folder in a file's path like the `/` in `/usr/bin`. The second one is a separator in a `path` environment variable, like the `;` in `PATH=C:/windows/bin;C:/anotherfolder`

Comment: what's the difference between File.separator and File.pathSeparator ?

Comment: `File.separator` is the char that separates parts of a file path e.g. `C:\dos` where the char is \ or `/home/user` where the char is `/`. The pathSeparator is the character that separates parts of the [PATH environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(variable)), which again is different depending on what OS your code are running on. Basically it's either a `;` or `:`

Comment: you still get an upvote from me though for a good answer :) Now if only I can make Markdown not keep escaping my backtick-backslash-backtick then I'll be very happy!

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `/` (forward slash) as the path separator. That will work cross-platform.

Comment: Unless you are on an old mac ;)

Comment: @Byron: true that. Does Java 5 or 6 actually run on OS 9-?

Answer (score 2):

`File` has a [separator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this before, except I'm not sure of its popularity.

```
System.getProperty("file.separator");
```